# Android location only works on WiFi

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, locationmanager

I'm having a problem trying to get locations in a Geocatching app on Android.

For some devices my app caches all the locations and for others devices only get locations on WiFi network. Despite on this, I checked on https://maps.google.com/locationhistory and Google got all locations.

I want to get data from both, mobile and WiFi. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? How can I make it work in all devices?

I'm using `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions btw.

This is an example the device that works ok, it collects mobile data as it follows the correct path:
[image: Good location]

And this, an example of the device that only works on WiFi. It links three points where I had WiFi connection.
[image]

Thanks in advance for your time!

EDIT: More info.

I get correct behaviour with HTC One, Android 4.2.2 and Nexus 5, Android 6.0.

With Sony Xperia Z3, Android 5.1.1 I only get locations when connected to WiFi.

Comment: what are you trying to do? both picture show working case

Comment: I'm trying to get location data from WiFi and mobile. First picture shows how the app is collecting data from mobile as it follows the path, second one shows only three points (where I got WiFi connection).

Comment: in second picture, do you use `gps and network` or `network only`?use this simple library if you want https://github.com/quentin7b/android-location-tracker

Comment: Both pictures are the same app with different device. It uses both GPS and Network to get accurate data. I don't need external libraries because I already had my app implemented (thanks for that).

Comment: Cuando todos los españoles usamos el Stack Overflow en inglés porque si no nadie se entera...